# jquery: ajax request not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am getting no responses when I try to fire this ajax request from jquery:

```
/********************************
CHANGE USER SETTINGS
*********************************/

$(".submitUserSetting").live('click', function() {

    //get values
    var department = $("#us_department").val(); 
    var sortOrder = $("input[@name=us_sortOrder]:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "lib/includes/updateUserSettings.php",
        data: "empname=" + empname + "&department=" + department + "&sortOrder=" + sortOrder,
        success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
        }
    });


});
```

I mean nothing. No javascript errors, no errors on the MySQL query, not even POST data in the console.log. Just a taunting batch o' silence. Even if I comment out all the code in the PHP page and just echo the data I sent over to it, nothing. Here's the PHP page (the class exists, the functions work, I'm using them on a dozen or so other pages)

```
 <?php

    require_once("../classes/mysqlconnect.php");
    $db = new dbconnect();
    $db->makeConnections("TimeSheetManager");

    $empname = $_POST['empname'];
    $department = $_POST['department'];
    $sortOrder = $_POST['sortOrder'];


    //get the department id
    $dQuery = "SELECT id FROM departments WHERE department = '" . $department . "'";
    $dResults = $db->getResults($query); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($dResults) > 0) { 
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($dResults) { 
            $deptID = $rows['id'];
        }
    } 


    //update database
    $query = "UPDATE users SET `department` = '" . $department "', `displayOrder` = '" .        $sortOrder . "' WHERE username = '" . $empname . "'"; 
    $results = $db->getResults($query); 

    if ($results) { 
        echo "!success"; 
    } else { 
        echo "!fail"; 
    }

    ?>
```

Here's the form code:

```
<div id="userSettingsForm">
        <form name="userSetting">
            <p><label for="sortOrder">Display Order:</label></p>
            <p class="userSettingElement">Oldest First&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="us_sortOrder" value="asc">&nbsp;&nbsp;Newest First&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="us_sortOrder" value="dsc"></p>
            <p><label for="us_department">Department:</label></p>
            <p class="userSettingElement">
                <select id="us_department" name="us_department">
                <option value="null">Select A Department</option>
                <?php 

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM departments";
                    $results = $db->getResults($query);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
                        if (count($results) > 0) { 
                            //get department and id
                            $department = $row['department'];
                            $deptID = $row['id'];

                            print "<option value=\"" . $deptID . "\">" . $department . "</option>";
                        }
                    }

                ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="submitUserSetting btn">Submit</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Thanks for all the help and suggestions. I rebooted Firefox and the error was in empname, I wasn't setting it (doh!). Beluga was on to that but it took a bit for it to dawn on me. Wish I could award everyone with the answer.

Comment: what is `empname` . on UPDATE get ride of single quotes on the table fields eg: `UPDATE users SET department...`

Comment: Is your site publicly availably? If so, could you post a link to the problematic page?

Comment: If you add a handler for the `failure` event, does anything appear?

Comment: Check using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see if the request is ever being made. Also, your code looks a little bit vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Can we see the markup that contains the element with the 'submitUserSetting' class, and the place where you invoke the 'live' call?

Comment: @kjy112 - empname is a string

Comment: @MattBell - no, it's internal

Comment: @belugabob - see the edits above - I know I'm not using mysql_real_escape (and other protections) but it's an internal site, no one using it has any coding skills, let alone hacker skills, probably should do it just for good practice and consistency though...

Comment: @Pruitgoe - that seems fine - how are you invoking the 'live' call?

Comment: Also, can you use some kind of debugegr to set a breakpoint in the 'click' function - to check if the code is even getting there, then step through to see where the error occurs.

Comment: @belugabob I've put alerts in the function and it goes through up till the ajax call, then nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the way you send the data.

Try enclosing the property in  `{ } 's` and changing the variable format to

```
{ "propertyName" : "value", "propertyName" : "value" }
```

i.e

```
 data: { "empname" : empname ,"department" : department, "sortOrder" :sortOrder }
```

alternatively if it is a form you can even say

```
data : { $("#form").serialize() }
```

Comment: tried that and still nothing. I can do an alert("ok") anywhere before the AJAX call, but anything after it's as if the js is being ignored.

Comment: have you tried using $.post instead of $.ajax ? it still uses $.ajax but straight $.ajax calls have been buggy in some versions

Answer (score 5):

How can you tell you're not getting an error?  Add an error handler to your .ajax() call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "lib/includes/updateUserSettings.php",
    data: "empname=" + empname + "&department=" + department + "&sortOrder=" + sortOrder,
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I worded that poorly, obviously there's an error since it doesn't work I just wasn't seeing one in the usual places.

Comment: Put your code in there and I still get nothing, no alert for errorThrown, no alert for data...grrrr

Comment: I guess the next step then would be to get Fiddler and inspect the post and the response.

Answer (score 3):

OK, some more investigation shows that the error is actually in a peculiar combination of pieces of code that you are using.

Apparently, `href="javascript:void(0)"` prevents event propagation. The event is triggered on the element itself (so handlers bound with `.click(fn)` work) but ancestor elements are not notified of the event.

Since you are using the `.live()` method, which relies upon event propagation, this doesn't work here.

I would suggest the following instead:

```
<a href="#" class="submitUserSetting btn">Submit</a>
```

and JS:

```
$(".submitUserSetting").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable the link action

    [snip]
});
```

[See jsFiddle demonstrating this.](http://jsfiddle.net/qf23b/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to return some value in your php function

Comment: I am (echo "!success or "!fail");

Answer (score 0):

data: "empname=" + empname + "&department=" + department + "&sortOrder=" + sortOrder,

define  empname in your call which is missing.

this gives you Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).